# Различия Borland C++ и Visual Studio C++ для Android

Tags: android, c++

Хотелось бы писать на C++ под Android, используя пакет SDK (то есть не все? а только вычислительную часть, разметку - на Java).

Какой из них подойдет для изучения C++ под Android?

Answer (score 2):

Писать на С++ под андроид целые программы - довольно бесполезное занятие. Все равно программы будут выполняться в JVM. Рекомендуется написание на C/C++ только отдельных частей программ, где возможности джавы оказываются ограниченными. А SDK лучше ставить под Eclipse.

Comment: Это я уже выяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше подойдет gcc+linux. Потому что в Андроиде используется именно g++.
Но проблема в том, что с пакетом SDK у Вас не получится писать, используя с++ (ну говоря уже о Borland C++ и Visual studio C++). Потому что для этого нужно скачать и установить себе NDK.

Comment: Какой компилятор используется в NDK?
Слышал что можно использовать SDK и NDK совместно, то есть разметка и  фреймворки используя Java, а всю вычислительную часть на C++

Comment: >> Какой компилятор используется в NDK?
gcc
>> Слышал что можно использовать SDK и NDK совместно
да, можно. Но есть одна проблема - накладные расходы на jni могут скушать все.

Comment: gcc компилирует код написанный в студии?

Comment: И возможно ли компилировать код C++(написанный в студе) со вставками асм.

Comment: В общем случае, gcc скомпилирует код, написанный в студии для компилятора MS C++ (или как он там правильно называется), но никто не обещает. Особенно, если MSC++ 6 версии.
А вот код с ассемблерными вставками... Вы понимаете, что студия в основном будет использовать ассемблер для x86/64, а андроид использует ARM???

Comment: Нет, я в этом вопросе плохо разбираюсь.

Comment: В общем случае, gcc скомпилирует код, написанный в студии для компилятора MS C++ (или как он там правильно называется), но никто не обещает. Особенно, если MSC++ 6 версии. А вот код с ассемблерными вставками... Вы понимаете, что студия в основном будет использовать ассемблер для x86/64, а андроид использует ARM???

Скорее в общем случае не скомпилирует =) А вставки вообще отдельная тема, не только у процов арзитектура разная, но и синтаксис у каждого компилятора свой, так что даже на один и тот же проц нужны разные вставки для разных компиляторов.

Answer (score 0):

Под Android надо писать прямо на NDK (основан GCC), Visual C++ и Borland C++ не имеют к нему вообще никакого отношения.